# Rank values in order of occurence within groups

Tags: r

I am currently trying to rank column values within groups of IDs in the order that they occur.
My dataset currently looks like this:

```
  ID Value      Date
1  1     a  1/1/2019
2  1     b  2/5/2018
3  1     a  3/3/2019
4  2     a 6/12/1975
5  2     b  5/4/2017
6  2     b 12/3/2016
7  3     c  1/3/2015
8  3     a  2/1/2015
9  4     a  1/1/1991
```

and I would like to add another column so that it looks like this:

```
  ID    Value   Date    Occurence
1  1     a  1/1/2019         1
2  1     b  2/5/2018         1
3  1     a  3/3/2019         2
4  2     a 6/12/1975         1
5  2     b  5/4/2017         2
6  2     b 12/3/2016         1
7  3     c  1/3/2015         1
8  3     a  2/1/2015         1
9  4     a  1/1/1991         1
```

So we can see, where `ID` is equal to `1`, `a` occurs twice and is ranked in order from oldest to newest and `b` is only ranked once because it only occurs once for `ID` `1`.

I have come across code to rank things in order of occurrence for the whole data set, but I would like to rank things in order of occurrence within IDs. There is also code to help me rank all dates within an ID...but I want to be able to look at individual values.

How would I do this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why row 5 gets Occurence 2 if it is the first occurence of the combination 2, b and the following row gets occurence 1. Do you want to sort by date first?

Comment: Hi Julian, you're right - the date makes it look a bit confusing! I am sorting by date - row 5 gets occurrence 2 because it has a later date than row 6.

Answer (score 2):

For the updated question with sorting by date:

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
mutate_at("Date",dmy) %>%  #convert to date-object
arrange(Date) %>%  #sort by date
group_by(ID,Value) %>%  #group by ID-Value pairs
mutate(Occurence = row_number()) #mutate new column with occurence

df
     ID Value Date       Occurence
  <int> <chr> <date>         <int>
1     2 a     1975-12-06         1
2     4 a     1991-01-01         1
3     3 a     2015-01-02         1
4     3 c     2015-03-01         1
5     2 b     2016-03-12         1
6     2 b     2017-04-05         2
7     1 b     2018-05-02         1
8     1 a     2019-01-01         1
9     1 a     2019-03-03         2
```

Comment: Hi Julian, I am getting this error: `Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 5007334
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.` what does this mean?

Comment: Looks like a problem with parsing the date. Does this error occur on the dataset you provided here?

Comment: Ah yes it did work with the dataset provided here. But on the actual data set I'm working with, no idea why it's not working `Error: incorrect size (1) at position 1, expecting : 5007334
> `

Comment: Thank you I got it! I just needed to change `arrange` to `arrange_at`. Would you be able to tell me what the difference between the two is?